# In Gradle (6.2), can we annotate constructor params of a custom task as "input"?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Say I have a custom gradle task:

```
open class CustomTask @Inject constructor(
    private val inputFile: File,
    private val outputFile: File
    ): DefaultTask()
```

(based on  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:passing_arguments_to_a_task_constructor )
.

In gradle, so far, the common way to define inputs or outputs is with annotations like [InputFile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/InputFile.html).

From a Kotlin-perspective, it would be nice to inject all these input/output values in the constructor, but I'm wondering,
is it possible? Something like:

```
open class CustomTask @Inject constructor(
    private @InputFile val inputFile: File,
    private @OutputFile val outputFile: File
): DefaultTask()
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it works like I asked above!

I didn't expect that it would, based on the docs, which is why I originally asked the question.

But the following task, defined like this in Kotlin (under `/buildSrc`) works:

```
open class TaskA @Inject constructor(
        @InputFile var inputFile : File,
        @OutputFile var outputFile : File
): DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun doIt() {
        val contents = inputFile.readText()
        val result = contents.replace("a", "b")
        outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
        outputFile.writeText(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The javadocs for both annotations state (emphasis mine):

[`@InputFile`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/InputFile.html)

> This annotation *should* be attached to the **getter method** in Java or **the property** in Groovy. **Annotations on setters or just the field in Java are ignored.**

[`@OutputFile`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/OutputFile.html)

> This annotation *should* be attached to the **getter method** in Java or **the property** in Groovy. Annotations **on setters or just the field in Java are ignored**.

To answer your question: no.

Constructor arguments in Kotlin, Java, or Groovy are neither getters nor properties so they are ignored.

Comment: Have you tried this? According to the docs, it seems like it wouldn't work. But I had in the meantime tried it, and it actually seems to work!